# How to get parent row id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

I'm creating an app that displays a list of documents and should be able to show attached scans of original documents. Tried to implement this via DevExtreme MasterDetailGrid and ASP views

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<QualityPassport>()
  .ShowBorders(true)
  .DataSource(d => d.WebApi()
      .RouteName("QualityPassport")
      .LoadAction("Get")
      .Key("Id"))
  .Columns(columns => {
      columns.AddFor(m => m.Id);
      columns.AddFor(m => m.DocNumber);
      columns.AddFor(m => m.DocDate);
      columns.AddFor(m => m.UserDescr);
      columns.AddFor(m => m.ScanDate);
      columns.AddFor(m => m.DocHexNrec);
  })
  .Paging(p => p.PageSize(20))
  .FilterRow(f => f.Visible(true))
  .HeaderFilter(f => f.Visible(true))
  .RemoteOperations(true)
  .MasterDetail(md =>
  {
md.Enabled(true);
md.Template(@<text><div class="master-detail-caption"> список файлов:
                  @(Html.Action("Index", "Image", new {id = new JS("data.Id")}))
                  </div>  </text>);
})
```

but in this case id is always null. If I set the id when debugging, the detail is shown. How to transfer data correctly?

Comment: By using aggregation

Comment: You can show an example code, please?

Comment: I try use <a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")/<%= data.id %>">Link Text</a>/ It worked as link, but i want get view